# What will Java API Runtime.getRuntime.availableProcessors() return in a Burstable Performance Amazon instance?

Tags: java, multithreading, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, processor

We are using Runtime.getRuntime.availableProcessors() to create my thread pool. Then every time a request (data intensive) comes in, we partition the data using the same availableProcessors API, and each thread of that thread pool processes one of those partitions.

So we rely on the fact that this API returns the same number any time it is called. Otherwise, what if at the time we create the thread pool availableProcessors is 3 and when the request comes in and we partition the data it is 15.

So now my question is what will this API return in a Burstable Performance Amazon instance?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tested it?  The number of logical processors on burstable instances doesn't change when you run low on credits -- they're just throttled -- so it should not change.

Comment: No I don't have the infrastructure to test this myself. Have to ask our DevOps team which would take some time. Was hoping if someone knew the answer already.

Comment: Not knowing how Java actually derives the value, I'd have to say I'm only ~99% sure it wouldn't change.